# Error while posting duplicate message in Twitter(MGTwitterEngine)

Tags: iphone, ipad, mgtwitterengine

I am using MGTwitterEngine for iPhone to support twitter, I am getting error(403) while posting a message second time how to handle this issue.

That is.. Let the message is "what are you doing" I am posting using [mTwitterEngine sendUpdate:"what are you doing"] for first time it is posted successfully, if i want to post the same message again it is throwing 403 error.

How to handle this? 
Can i put the alert "Duplicate message" if error no 403? Is 403 error for duplicate messages only?

**Added :** *Is it possible to check if an message is already posted in MGTwitterEngine?*

Comment: Why do you want to publish the same message twice? The Twitter API prevents you to do that, so the problem is not tied to MGTwitterEngine IMHO.

Comment: Is it possible to check if an message is already posted in MGTwitterEngine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 403 error is not only for duplicate message so that you cannot throw the error message to user.

http://developer.twitter.com/pages/responses_errors

You have to find the duplicate message in your application code by keeping the last updated message.